# How to add kyeup:13 on popup modal in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I want <kbd>enter</kbd> key should work on popup window.

I tried this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  v-on:click="renameFolder(folder.Id)"  v-on:keyup.13="renameFolder(folder.Id)">Rename</button>
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd> key does not work

Comment: Works here, please share more details

Comment: If I click the button first and then try for enter key then it works. If I try enter key first then it does not work.  I applied keyup.13 on input instead of button and now it is working.